# Getting value from json parameter doesn't work (jq: 1 compile error)

Tags: sed, syntax, syntax-error, jq

I am using awscli and trying to get the value of **IpAddress** from the output of my query.

I tried to use **jq** but I get a compile error.

This is the case:

```
output="$(aws efs describe-mount-targets --file-system-id fs-089b5e31)"
echo $output
{ "MountTargets": [ { "MountTargetId": "fsmt-bb29e666", "IpAddress": "172.20.33.255", "OwnerId": "668225551666", "SubnetId": "subnet-0b61377039d31e666", "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-045f6ea1376662bdf", "FileSystemId": "fs-089b5e66", "LifeCycleState": "available" } ] }
```

And this is the command I am using to get the IpAddress:

```
echo array | jq '.[]MountTarget[]s.IpAddress'
```

The error I get is this:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
ubuntu@ip-10-10-16-245:~/infra-devops/kops/vector$ echo array | jq '.[]MountTarget[]s.IpAddress'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[]MountTarget[]s.IpAddress
jq: 1 compile error
```

Is my query is the problem or maybe I better use sed instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax to access array is wrong. To get the IP address, use this:

```
aws efs describe-mount-targets --file-system-id fs-089b5e31 | 
  jq '.MountTargets[0].IpAddress'
```

The `MountTargets` is an array from which you want the first object.

If you need raw data (without double quotes) use `-r` option in the `jq` command.